# can you have multiple formats within a fieldset legend

Tags: html, css, fieldset

is there anyway to have a fieldset legend have different formats.  For example, title would be big but sub title would be small?

Title:  sub title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<legend>Title: <span class="subtitle">Subtitle</span></legend>
```

CSS:

```
fieldset legend .subtitle { font-size: 80%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Multiple FieldSet Nested FieldSet](http://csscreator.com/node/30315)

Comment: i changed the question as i had a typo

Answer (score 1):

The `<legend>` element can contain any [inline element](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/inline.html), so you can apply virtually whatever formatting you'd like.